# how to optimize setting theme suggestion for different languages?

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

I've been trying to look for a way on how to optimize theme suggestions for different languages. The code below is a snippet of what I have been working on.

One is for english and one is for Spanish. Is there a way I can minimize this into a single code instead of breaking it down for multiple languages?

```
// Template based on current url
// News Press Room

if ($current_url == '/iom/news-press-room') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__news_press_room';
}

// News Press Room(Spanish)

if ($current_url == '/iom/es/news-press-room') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__news_press_room';
}
```

Comment: Is this Drupal 8 or 7?

Comment: @IsmailCherri yes, this is Drupal 8

Comment: I think the question title could be misunderstood. If your code should not depend on the language you could try to get the information from the current route instead of the current path. Which is preferable in most cases anyway, because normally a page is based on a resolved route, not on a path.

Comment: @4k4 sorry for my ignorance, I'm having difficulty trying to wrap my head around your suggestion. Especially getting the `current route` part

Comment: You didn't provide any details about the content you display. For example if this is a node, then you can get the node id from the raw route parameter `node`, independently from the alias or language prefix in the path.

Comment: @4k4 Correct if I'm wrong, so basically I should get the `node ID` instead of using the `url` of the page or node I'm targeting to setup the template path?

Comment: Yes, because there may be dozens of paths leading to one node.

Answer (score 1):

Check the example in [hook_theme_suggestions_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.6.x) for language (second one below)
You can add more specific suggestions by appending the content type.